# Octopus Deploy: Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown

Tags: octopus-deploy

I trying to access Octopus after restarting the Octopus service from the server hosting it.

I ran into this error below:

> Exception of type 'System.OutOfMemoryException' was thrown octopus

And this is not allowing me to access the application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I fixed it:

The issue was caused by a synchronization task which was **Synchronize Community Step Templates** which I found out after waiting for a while (about 3 mins)

This synchronization task took a lot of system memory:

[image]